# Pycapa to kafka topic - bogue or undecoded characters

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to capture live packets from a network interface using Pycapa from Metron,but when i try to consume the messages from the topic, i am receiving the following strange characters.

```
!i�f�U�_� ��mP�pO���62.��a#;�k��o��0�?
!i�f�U�_� ��mP�pO���62.��a#;�k��o��0�?
```

I am **not** using Confluent platform. In this case, can someone guide me to a solution?

Thank you

[image: messages from topic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [the docs](https://metron.apache.org/current-book/metron-sensors/pycapa/index.html#Usage) it looks like pycapa stores *the raw network packet data*, which is probably what you're seeing here.

If you look at [the examples](https://metron.apache.org/current-book/metron-sensors/pycapa/index.html#Examples) you'll see there's one for consuming this raw data and piping it into something like tshark which can read the raw data and render it readable:

```
pycapa --consumer \
    --kafka-broker localhost:9092 \
    --kafka-topic ciscotopic1 \
    --max-packets 10 \
    | tshark -i -
```

Comment: Hi Robin, i saw that example, but i am interested more in producer, means that i would like to capture all packets, send them to kafka topic, and from there i will analyze using flink

Comment: Re-read my answer. The point is not to use the example, but to point out that it shows how to decode the data you've got in the topic.

Comment: btw you might be interested in https://rmoff.net/2020/03/11/streaming-wi-fi-trace-data-from-raspberry-pi-to-apache-kafka-with-confluent-cloud/